# C# how can I access the object properties that not exist in the implemented interface

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, interface, polymorphism

Please consider the following code. I have an interface named IClass.

```
public interface IClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And I have two classes that implements this interface:

```
public class ClassA : IClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB : IClass
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

And finally I have a method that returns IClass interface:

```
public static IClass MethodA()
{
    return new ClassB { MyProperty = "A", MyProperty2 = "B" };
}
```

My problem is I can't access the MyProperty2 from the MethodA

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(MethodA()));
}
```

It is only returning `{"MyProperty":"A"}` How can I actually get the MyProperty2 without using polymorphic model binding?  Is there any other ways?

Comment: `MethodA() as ClassB`?

Comment: What exactly did you mean?

Comment: You need to case the object returned by the method to `ClassB`. Either use `(ClassB)MethodA()` or `MethodA() as ClassB`.

Comment: See my answer for some alternatives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast

```
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize((ClassB) MethodA()))
```

However, doing so kind of defeats the purpose of using an interface in the first place.

Comment: Thank your for your answer sir but actually this is a simple example. In a real scenario I don't have a chance to cast because of generic methods. Is there any other ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes, you need to use reflection to figure out the underlying class at runtime, then loop through the various methods and invoke them also via reflection.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties

Comment: Thank you I will check out :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will have to check and cast it explicitly like

```
var data = MethodA();
JsonSerializer.Serialize(data is ClassB ? data as ClassB : data as ClassA )
```

Comment: There's no best type for the ternary operator. This will fail to compile with CS0173

Answer (score 0):

Serialization is based off of the type information you supply. In the case of the generic overloads, this is the generic type (the `T` in `Serialize<T>`). You are calling one of the generic overloads and type-inference is picking up `IClass`. To get around this, use the [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serialize?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializer_Serialize_System_Object_System_Type_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_) that accepts a `Type`:

```
var obj = MethodA();
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj, obj.GetType(), default);
```

Or explicitly cast to `object` so that the generic type is inferred as `object`:

```
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize((object)MethodA(), default);
```

Or, a semi-combination of the two:

```
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(MethodA(), typeof(object), default);
```

If you don't want this behavior from the serializer, you would have to cast to the explicit type (assuming you know it and/or can live with a bunch of type checks)

```
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize((ClassB) MethodA(), default);
```

Note that the `object` solution will only work at the top-level/root object. If you have a property somewhere in your object graph that is declared as `IClass` it won't serialize how you want. You'd unfortunately have to declare those properties with the `object` type.

The alternative would be writing a [custom converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to) for your interface type and reflecting over the properties yourself. While overkill for a root object (given the solutions above) it would allow you to handle nested objects of your interface type. A simple converter *could* delegate to the object's real type.

```
public class IClassConverter : JsonConverter<IClass> 
{
     public override IClass Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) => throw new NotImplementedException();

     public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        IClass obj,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
     {
         JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, obj, obj.GetType(), default); // don't pass options, will result in endless loop 
     } 
}
```

You then use it by adding your converter to the Serializer Options:

```
var opts = new JsonSerializerOptions();
opts.Converters.Add(new IClassConverter());
IClass obj = MethodA();
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj, opts);
```